# Real time mobile location tracking and auto distance calculation

Tags: web, mobile, geolocation, maps, tracking

I want to create a web application and mobile appilcation system, to track in real time the location of the mobile devices that have that app installed, then in the web app will be the admin dashboard that there will be a map and shows the real time location of the mobile devices and the client dashboard that will have a button and when the client clicks that button, the system should calculate the nearest mobile device location and send a push notification to this device.

Which technology stack you think is best to use in that case project?

I am familiar with c# and .net but i am not sure that this is the best approach.

Thank you in advance!

I just want the opinion of all people in the forum.